# How to modify IIS handler mapping permissions via Wix or a Custom Action

Tags: c#, iis, wix

I'm using Wix to create an installer for a Silverlight application.

When I install the application the virtual directory that has been created has the execute permission checked for the *.dll handler mapping (IIS 7 > Web site > VDir > Handler Mappings > *.dll > Edit Feature Permissions > Execute).

When I browse to the application it cannot download its satellite assemblies in ClientBin.  If I uncheck the execute permission in IIS the handler becomes disabled and the application now works.

I don't want to have to do this manually.  Does anybody know how to modify the handler mapping permissions in Wix or a Custom Action?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in a VBScript Custom Action.

```
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject _
    ("winmgmts:{authenticationLevel=pktPrivacy}\\" _
        & strComputer & "\root\microsoftiisv2")

vdir = "W3SVC/1/ROOT"

Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("Select * from IIsWebVirtualDirSetting WHERE Name = '" & vdir & "'")

For Each objItem in colItems
    ''WScript.Echo objItem.AppRoot
    objItem.AccessExecute = "False"
    objItem.Put_()
Next
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'll look into implementing this when I'm given the time.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this post](http://www.mail-archive.com/wix-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg35256.html), it is not possible directly from WiX. However you could write a [managed custom action](http://blogs.msdn.com/josealmeida/archive/2004/11/08/wix-managed-custom-actions.aspx) and use the [IIS7 .net API](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/165/how-to-use-microsoftwebadministration/) to edit the mapping.